# what is the meaning of struct pointer end with a pointer? c++

Tags: c++, struct

What is this meaning of the *head follows the struct here?

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}*head;
```

Comment: Or a C book. They are different languages, so get the book for the language you actually learn/use.

Answer (score 6):

`head` is a pointer variable to `struct node`. This is equivalent of writing:

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;
```

On another note, though this is perfectly valid C++, this concept and your code is much related to C. However, if you use C++ compiler then you can simply write `node *head;`, i.e. on C++ you can omit the `struct` portion while declaring the `head` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as writing

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
node* head;
```

I dont really remember why, but it is more common in C to write it like your version.

Comment: `node` is not a type in C, this is C++. `struct node` is the type.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The question is about C++. See the original version of the question (now it's edited by other people) and the title. stackoverflow.com/revisions/38500447/1

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the c tag was added later. Actually I have the impression that it was added to make another answer fit better to the question and I removed it again, because if OP wants to know about C++, the C tag is rather misplaced.

Comment: I added C tag as I thought it's more related to C, not C++. But I didn't edit the title which clearly stated C++. However, since there is a slight difference between C and C++ here, it's better to remove C tag, i.e. keep the original tags that OP used.